# How to use custom dimension in Analytics reporting in php

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am setting up a reporting script which gets data from google analytics .I am adding three dimensions to get the data but one of the those dimensions is custom dimension named *test_dimension*. When i set this dimension i get this error.

Unknown dimension(s): test_dimension

I tried the developer API but cannot get the expected results
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns&jump=ga_dimensionxx

```
$custom = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$custom->setName("test_dimension");

$campaign = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$campaign->setName("ga:campaign");

$sourceMedium = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$sourceMedium->setName("ga:sourceMedium");

$request->setDimensions(array($custom,$campaign,$sourceMedium));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

I expect the output with the applied dimensions. If i remove the custom dimension the code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the index of the custom dimension (e.g. `ga:dimension03`) instead of its name. The index is visible in the property's admin settings under *Custom Definitions*.